# Why expires is not working in mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So this is my model and I want to do that when it's created in DB to remove it from there after one hour. But this not working. I got no errors also. It expires after few seconds.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Revive = mongoose.model('Revive', {
   username: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   count: {
       type: Number,
       default: 0,
       max: 4
   },
expire_at : { type : Date, index : { expires : '60m' }, default: Date.now }

});
module.exports = {Revive};
```

Comment: the expires isn't inside index, try it. expire_at : { type : Date, expires : '60m', default: Date.now }

Comment: @MiltonFilho Doesn't work. Expire at fiels sets current date and time.